# MD5 Python implementation giving unexpected results

Tags: python, hash, md5

I have written the following attempted implementation/minimum runnable example of the MD5 hash based on its [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5):

```
import numpy as np
import math

# List of shifts taken from Wikipedia
shifts = np.array([
    7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,
    5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,
    4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,
    6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21
], dtype = np.uint8)

# Procedure for generating these terms, also from Wikipedia
K = np.zeros(64, dtype = np.uint32)
for i in range(64):
    K[i] = int(abs(math.sin(i + 1)) * 2 ** 32)

# Starting terms from... Wikipedia
a0 = np.uint32(0x67452301)
b0 = np.uint32(0xefcdab89)
c0 = np.uint32(0x98badcfe)
d0 = np.uint32(0x10325476)

def md5(message):
    '''Digest message via MD5.
    Message given as bytes like object'''
    length = len(message)
    # Pad with one 1 bit, then zero bits, then the length LE-order (8 bytes) so that is a multiple of 64 bytes
    padded = message + b'\x80' + b'\0' * ((56 - length - 1) % 64) + (length << 3).to_bytes(8, 'little')
    
    a, b, c, d = a0, b0, c0, d0
    for chunk_no in range(len(padded) // 64):
        a1, b1, c1, d1 = a, b, c, d
        chunk = padded[chunk_no * 64 : (chunk_no + 1) * 64]
        
        # Break the chunk up into 16 4-byte LE words
        M = np.array([int.from_bytes(chunk[j * 4 : (j + 1) * 4], 'little') for j in range(16)], dtype = np.uint32)
        for i in range(64):
            quarter = i >> 4
            if quarter == 0:
                f = (b1 and c1) or ((~b1) and d1)
                g = i
            elif quarter == 1:
                f = (d1 and b1) or ((~d1) and c1)
                g = (5 * i + 1) & 15
            elif quarter == 2:
                f = b1 ^ c1 ^ d1
                g = (3 * i + 5) & 15
            else:
                f = c1 ^ (b1 or (~d1))
                g = (7 * i) & 15
            f = (f + a1 + K[i] + M[g]) & 0xffffffff
            a1, d1, c1, b1 = d1, c1, b1, (b1 + ((f << shifts[i]) | (f >> (32 - shifts[i])))) & 0xffffffff
        a = (a + a1) & 0xffffffff
        b = (b + b1) & 0xffffffff
        c = (c + c1) & 0xffffffff
        d = (d + d1) & 0xffffffff
    a, b, c, d = int(a), int(b), int(c), int(d) # Allow shifting past the limits of the uint32 type
    return (d << 96) | (c << 64) | (b << 32) | a

def test():
    data = b''
    digest = md5(data)
    print(f'MD5({data}) = {digest:032x}')
```

According to the same article, the empty string of bytes, which I pass as a test input, should return `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`. Instead, I get `b6ea9854c6e3520c278e5a1bdeda64da`. In case the Wikipedia article is using null-terminated strings instead of just the plain byte representation that I have above, I also find that my implementation yields `md5(b'\0') = e9bd4ae5b18e3f1728405b15138df6ca`, which, too, is not the expected value.

I do not see any glaringly obvious mistakes in my implementation so far, and thanks to all the iterated operations and bit jumbling, I'm unsure as to where my mistakes lie.

In all cases where bytes are put together to form a word, or vice versa, I use little-endian encoding, which appears to be the convention by [rfc1321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1321). Though not included in the above code, I have been able to debug at least to the point that I know my `K` is consistent with the table given on Wikipedia, and that my message is padded to 64 bytes total length, with the final 8 bytes being the little endian encoding of the initial bit count. All I can think to do now is to ask if anyone spots any mistakes in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pretty simple yet hard to find mistake, it seems. I used Python's logical `and` and `or` in a few places where I should have used the bitwise `&` and `|`.